# Highlight the first page pagination_links

Tags: paginate-links

i need help in WordPress. I'm not a WordPress developer, but for some reason i have to change some code in here. Now coming to the point.

I have a page where i'm showing some content with pagination. Im using `paginate_links()` to generate the pagination. When i'm in the first page, page number not highlighting it. But from 2nd page its highlighting the page number. But i also want to highlight the first. Here is my code i used:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'base' => '%_%',
    'format' => '#page%#%',
    'total' => $sitesQuery->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $page,
    'show_all' => false,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'end_size' => 2
);
echo paginate_links($args);
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image: Second Page Selected]

You need to add style for the class .current also current page number wrapper in span you can also use this to style.

[image: Current Page Selected]

[image]

```
 <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
 <a class="page-numbers" href="#page2">2</a>
 <a class="next page-numbers" href="#page2">Next »</a>
```

When you go to page 2 structure become

```
 <a class="prev page-numbers" href="">« Previous</a>
 <a class="page-numbers" href="">1</a>
 <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
```

Tested your code its working fine all you need to do is add style for it.

```
 .current{
     background:yellow;
     padding:10px;
 }
```

Comment: This is what i did,, Used jquery to insert the class. Thanks for your reply